# How to autologin as root to mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, root, autologin, mdm

I would like to know how to autologin as root on mint 17.1?

I've been able to login as root from the login screen (by enabling root access in login window settings and changing the theme to clouds).

But I have been unable to auto login (meaning that I don't have to enter my password).

I tried editing `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf`, and writing:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=root
```

but that doesn't work (works for normal accounts though).

Does anyone have clue how to do it? I'm doing this just for testing so please don't tell me its not a good idea. I know its not a good idea to be root and I am doing it for research purpose only.

Comment: First you need [to enable the root account](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login).  Once the account is enabled your config change should work...  See also, [RootSudo Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: It doesnt. Have you tried it? The problem is in mdm code...

Comment: Consider Stopping `mdm`, then try [this approach](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168706/how-do-i-auto-login-as-root-into-the-tty-upon-boot), then use `startx`

Comment: if you read my question i need root auto login. not manual. i can do manual no problem. have you tried your approach and does it give auto root login? meaning when you turn on your computer after everything is loaded you are root? as i said previously i can login manually as root no problem

Comment: Why would anyone want to log into his / her system as root? Consider the inevitable security hole. Even if we knew the answer, should we share it?

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings click Login Window. Click tab for Options click Allow Root Login

Comment: that only allows root login. What I wanted to do is to auto login with root (so i dont have to enter username password)

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found is to rid of `mdm`. There are other display managers like `nodm`, `gdm`, `lightdm` that you can install and configure them to autologin as root. There is also a issue about it on [GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm/issues/137) which seems to be closed.